# How to replace text with placeholders with values from variable in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I've two variables. One is the text with placeholders e.g. `&a` or `&B`. The other one contains the variables which should be inserted in the text. `&a` says it's the first word, `&b` says it's the second word. In the text they could be in random order. Delimiter is a whitespace. How could I do this in bash?

Example:

```
TEXT="Once &B a &a"
VAR="time upon"

# Result should be "Once upon a time"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure bash - without external commands:

```
VAR="time upon"
TEXT="Once &b a &a"
set -- $VAR
temp=${TEXT//&a/$1}
TEXT=${temp//&b/$2}
echo ==$TEXT==
```

Comment: Thanks this works like a charm. Sorry that I missed to say that there could be up to 26 placeholders (a-z) AND sometimes there are not as much variables as placeholders. Eg. TEXT="Once &b a &c there &a peace &d &e &f"; VAR="was upon time"

Answer (score -1):

You need to use at least these 2 commands :

- cut (to split your "VAR" variable)
- sed (to replace your tokens)

Comment: This does not help - how should one use these command? Please add an example and explanation. Temporarily downvoted.

Comment: Now you have the good keywords (sed and cut), you can copy/paste them in google, can't you ? Before you had them, you couldn't, so I do think it helps. SO is not a place to do someone else homework.